# For $\forall$ x $\in$ [0,1], $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} f(x+n)=0$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

I encountered a proof question:

Suppose $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,+\infty)$. For $\forall$ x $\in$ [0,1], $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} f(x+n)=0$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

The question is whether the uniform continuity of $f(x)$ is necessary. When I use $x-[x]$ to represent $x\in [0,1]$, use $[x]$ to represent $n$, then $n\to +\infty$ means $[x] \to +\infty$, which can deduce $x\to+\infty$, then complete the proof. But condition uniform continuity of $f(x)$ is not used. Can someone point out the loopholes of my proof?

Comment: What about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886005/a-variant-of-heine-definition-of-limit-can-x-n-be-x-n-where-x-in-0-1

Comment: The above question was not clearly stated, so I asked again.

Comment: I don't see your proof is complete. Please elaborate.

Comment: I agree with @ArcticChar ... the suggested argument is faulty.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to find a counterexample which shows that even if $f$ is continuous, and, for all $x\in[0,1]$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=0$, this is not enough to conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)= 0$ (hence, you need something stronger than continuity to conclude). Consider a function $f$ defined as follows: For $n\ge 2$, let $I_n=[1/n+n-1/n^2, 1/n+n+1/n^2]$, and let $f$ be a continous function s.t.:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x\notin \bigcup_n I_n\\
>0 & x\in \bigcup_n I_n\\
1 & x\in \bigcup_n \{1/n +n\}
\end{cases}
$$
[image: here an illustration of this function]

This function doesn't converge to 0. However:

For $x=0, x+n\notin I_n=[(1/n-1/n^2)+n, (1/n+1/n^2)+n]$ for any $n$, thus $f(x+n)=0$ for all $n$. Same for $x > 3/4$.

For $x\in (0, 3/4]$, there will be some instant $n_0$ s.t. for all $n\ge n_0$, $x>1/n + 1/n^2$, thus, $x+n\notin I_n=[(1/n-1/n^2)+n, (1/n+1/n^2)+n]$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Hence, $f(x+n)=0$ for all $n\ge n_0$

In short, for all $x\in[0,1]$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=0$.

As for errors in your proof. You say that, if you take a sufficiently large $x$, then $x=(x-[x]) + [x]$ with $[x]$ large, and because $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x-[x]+n)=0$, $f(x)$ will be small. The problem I'd say is that for some such $x$, the sequence $(f(x-[x]+n))_n$ may fall to zero much later than at the instant $[x]$

Comment: maybe it is a bad idea to use $n$ for both the limit variable and the sets $I_n$. I also don't understand what the index in $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x+n)_n$ means.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Thanks. Indeed, the indexes inside the limits were misleading. Nice graphic of the function, btw.